# How to fix E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to install zabbix 3.2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 but when ever I enter this command

```
apt-get install zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-frontend-php
```

I got an error would you please tell me how to fix it 
here's the error:

```
apt-get install zabbix-server-pgsql zabbix-frontend-phpReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zabbix-server-pgsql : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4~dfsg) but 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
                       Recommends: postgresql (>= 8.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: snmpd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@ubuntu:/home/siwar# sudo apt install -f 

Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded
```

Comment: try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: i already tried it it shows that 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded

Comment: please post the complete error mesasge.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/siwar# sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zabbix-server-pgsql : Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4~dfsg) but 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
                       Recommends: postgresql (>= 8.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: snmpd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please post these error messages in you question.

Comment: i can't, it s too large but the real probleme is "E:unable to correct problems,you have held broken packages"

Comment: i already edited it would you please check the errors

Comment: Where do you install the `zabbix-server-pgsql` from? Is it some PPA? This version won't install to 14.04.

Comment: so #pilot6 u suggest to change the version !!

Answer (score 0):

may be Remove or comment yours zabbix ppa in /etc/apt/sources.list since it may be not meet with yours ubuntu dependencies then update "sudo apt-get update", sudo "apt-get dist-upgrade", sudo apt-get "autoremove" then "sudo apt-get remove libsnmp30 and reinstall it (libsnmp30)

I dont know what zabbix is since i try istall it from ubuntu repository said E: Unable to locate package zabbix

Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: i have already fixed it thank you for your suggestion and zabbix is a an enterprise-class open source distributed monitoring solution